# Delete a dictionary from another dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

If A and B are two dictionaries, using python, is there any way of removing elements from Dictionary A that are in dictionary B?

For example,

```
parent_dict = {"a" : "aaa", "b" : "bbb", "c" : "ccc", "d" : "ddd", "e": "eee"}
derived_dict = {"a" : "aaa", "d" : "ddd", "e" : "eee"}
```

Now I need to write a function dict_reduce(dictA, dictB) which deletes all the elements of dictB from dictA.

(i.e.,) dict_reduce(parent_dict, derived_dict) should give
{"b" : "bbb", "c" : "ccc"}

My work around with a for loop is:

```
def dict_reduce(parent_dict, child_dict):
    for key in child_dict.keys():
        del parent_dict[key]
    return parent_dict

reduced_dict = dict_reduce(parent_dict, child_dict)
```

NOTE:

1. It will be great if the solution is a one liner or something which
   do not takes a for loop.
2. Also we need not to check whether parent
   dictionary has the key before deleting, since the child dictionary
   is derived from the parent dictionary. So need not think about
   keyError.
3. The parent dictionary is a static dictionary which should not be affected by the method. Instead the returning dictionary should be stored in another reduced dictionary.
4. There is no need to check whether the child_dict has same key as that of parent_dict. Only the key matters.

Comment: What's your issue with using a `for` loop? Your function looks perfectly clear and once you've written the function any time you use it is a one liner and is also readable. Nobody gets prizes for writing overly smart obscure code when a three line function does the job.

Comment: your _workaround_ affects `parent_dict`, is it what you want?

Comment: @Duncan I have no issues with using a for loop. But my situation is to work with a dictionary generated by a rrd tool. So I am kind of trying to reduce the number of for loops. It takes hell lot of time for my application to process. If there is a solution without a for loop then I can definitely make use of it.

Comment: @neurino parent_dict should not be affected as it is the dictionary used throughout the code. I will update my question accordingly. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @thiruvenkadam: whatever you will end up using, `map`, `filter`, list comprehensions or other you will ever end with a for loop underneath even if you don't find it explicitly written ...

Comment: Ya... I understand that we should iterate through a loop... But an inline for loop or an implicit for loop is faster than an explicit for loop. Since improving my application's performance is my goal, I am going for implicit for instead of explicit for

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
{k: v for k, v in parent_dict.items() if k not in derived_dict}
```

Comment: Removes duplicate keys that have different values.

Comment: @DrTyrsa Cool... It is working like a charm for me. I can easily assign it to a new dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

Using the dictionaries provided in the question:
dict(parent_dict.items() - derived_dict.items()) or
dict(parent_dict.items() ^ derived_dict.items())

Comment: Add some context to your code to help future readers better understand its meaning.

Comment: As the author does not want to improve: ^ operator = elements which are in dict1 but not in dict2 and elements which are in dict2 but not in dict1

Answer (score 0):

```
map(lambda k: del parent_dict[k], child_dict.keys())
```

Comment: `del` is a statement, and can't be placed in a `lambda`.

Comment: Oops! That's absolutely right. Sorry. Note for the future: always test the snippet before posting, especially if you are currently working in a different language!

Answer (score 0):

If affect `parent_dict` is what you want this does the job

```
map(parent_dict.pop, filter(lambda k: k in derived_dict, parent_dict))
```

(and also returns duplicate keys)

This variant will also check (if requiered) that also values match:

```
map(parent_dict.pop, filter(lambda k: k in derived_dict and derived_dict[k] == parent_dict[k], parent_dict))
```

Comment: parent_dict should not be affected. I have included the note along with the question now. Thanks for pointing it out.